# Как сделать так, чтобы изображение метки визуально было одного размера на устройствах с разным разрешением экрана и ppi?

Tags: java, android, yandexmapkit

Задаю иконку метки таким образом:

```
locationImage = ImageProvider.fromResource(MainActivity.this, R.drawable.location).getImage();
myPlacemark.setIcon(ImageProvider.fromBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(locationImage, 70, 200, false)));
```

Тестирую на устройстве с экраном 2340×1080, около 400 ppi. Метки отображаются как нужно. Если же запускаю в эмуляторе на телефоне с экраном, у которого размер, разрешение и ppi поменьше, то метки там выглядят огромными.

Как это можно решить, может какую-то формулу использовать?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities

Comment: @Эникейщик, спасибо, очень помогли

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решено на основе [этой статьи](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities).

Сначала рассчитано по формуле из статьи нужное значение в dp.

Дальше dp преобразую в px в зависимости от характеристик экрана (`PLACEMARK_WIDTH_DP` и `PLACEMARK_HEIGHT_DP` - константы, содержащие значение ширины и длины метки в dp):

```
placemarkWidthPx = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(
            COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
            PLACEMARK_WIDTH_DP,
            getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

placemarkHeightPx = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(
            COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
            PLACEMARK_HEIGHT_DP,
            getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

После этого размеры метки задаю, исходя из рассчитанных значений:

```
myPlacemark.setIcon(ImageProvider.fromBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(locationImage, placemarkWidthPx, placemarkHeightPx, false)));
```